# What programs to use for Animated Cartoon Video

Tags: macos, video, video-editing, animation

I want to make a video similar to this one, which includes a lot of animation and text (**click to view**):

[image]

But what software would you use for this? Would Illustrator + After Effects be enough?

Comment: Or would you suggest use of totally different apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already ask like this:

Yes, Illustrator is a great tool to generate vector art, and After Effecs can be used to generate animations using vector graphics. In fact, I think After Effects is the most popular animation tool these days for two-dimensional editing. For 3D animation, [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) comes to mind.

If you look on YouTube for animated vector art with After Effects, you [will find](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEwHAD7m1sM) plenty [of examples](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuSs1cVxPlg&feature=related). Vimeo even has a [channel for After Effects animations](http://vimeo.com/channels/aftereffects).

For getting into animation, you will need to read up and get to know the software. The internet has plenty of tutorials, [like this one](http://www.computerarts.co.uk/tutorials/animate-character-after-effects), which shows you how to animate a character.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Synfig could be the right tool for you  http://www.synfig.org/cms/  There's a Mac version on the downloads page.